# Can't use class from .jar in Build Path

Tags: eclipse, jar

I have two Android workspaces, and I would like to use the same class for both. I want to import instead of just copy and paste the class (just to learn how to import .jar and/or the classpath folder).

### Creating my .jar

On my first Android application:

`right click on my project folder --> Export... --> Java --> JAR File --> Next`

Then this is what would come up:

[image]

Then I click finish.

There are 20+ classes in that app, but one of them is `CopyPaste.java` located like so in my project:

`Calculator\src\com.mikeyaworski.calculator\CopyPaste.java`

### Adding .jar to build path (other workspace)

`right click on project folder --> Build Path --> Configure Build Path... --> Libraries --> Add External JARs...` and then I choose it.

It'll look like this afterward:

[image]

### Using a class from the .jar

I add this import statement:

```java
import com.mikeyaworski.calculator.CopyPaste;
```

But it gives me the error:

> The import com.mikeyaworski.calculator.CopyPaste cannot be resolved

Then I would just try to create an instance of the class like this:

```java
CopyPaste c = new CopyPaste(getApplicationContext());
```

### Questions

- How can I get rid of that error?
- If I add an `External Class Folder` to the build path instead, how can I use that to use a class? I've done that, but I don't know how to import the class from the class folder to my other class.